# How do I set the Google Form to automatically send to another user in HTML format other than respondent?

Tags: forms

How do I set the form to automatically send to another user in HTML so it looks like the one the user gets when the user checks the "Send me a copy of my responses" box? I can't figure out how to set a script and/or trigger to send the HTML form to a user other than the respondent.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with google apps scripting, in particular the function MailApp.sendEmail.  For HTML messages be sure to make use of the advanced parameters like htmlBody.

Check out the MailApp class for full details:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app